# Splitting background processing

Tags: php

I am not a PHP expert, so please bear with me.

If I have a page (start.php), which contains a textbox and a submit button, which the user should see.

How do I direct the serverside to a specific php file in the background (which the user does not see) which contain further instructions.  For example,

The following are very simplified examples, they do not reflect the complexity of the actual files. Lets say (process1.php) creates a session containing the string "process 1 was used", and (process2.php) creates a session containing "process 2 was used".

Now, if the textbox in (start.php) is empty, the "process1.php" file should be used, if the textbox in (start.php) is filled, the "process2.php" file should be used.  Each of which should then go to the page "finish.php", which the user should see, which will echo the content of the session created by either "process1.php" or "process2.php" on the screen for the user to see.

Can such a think be done with php, should such a thing be done with php, if yes, how?  if no, how should I go about doing this?  i.e. splitting complex process into possible multiple files to make things easier as a developer for maintenance purposes in the future?

Please note, process1.php or process2.php should not be accessable or viewable by the user directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of doing this is to put your input element within a form element, which takes a single .php file as its action. `<form action="process.php">`. You would most likely want to have your processing logic done there:

```
if(strlen($_GET['inputname']))
{
    include('process1.php');
}
else
{
    include('process2.php');
}
```

Now, having said that, there are *much* better ways of implementing this, using OO concepts. For example:

form.php:

```
class MyForm
{
    private $_val;
    public __construct()
    {
        $this->_val = null;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $this->_val = isset($_GET['txtfield']) ? $_GET['txtfield'] : null;
        if(strlen($this->_val) > 0)
        {
            $this->processEmpty();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->processText();
        }
    }

    public function processEmpty()
    {
        // do your processing if text field is empty here
    }

    public function processText()
    {
        // do your processing with input here
    }
}
```

And then your process.php file might looking something like this:

```
require_once('myform.php');
$f = new MyForm();
$f->process();
```

I'd most likely start reviewing OO concepts prior to building your system. Following OO design makes things *much* more modular and extensible for future work than legacy style scripting.

**Edit**

*Disclaimer:* The above code is just a sample - I didn't actually try running it, so it might not work at all ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are talking about is post processing and not background processing.

You can use if else around include (after your submit)
here is a pseudo for you

```
if(<form submitted>){
$accessKey = '1234';
    if(<text box empty>){
    include process1
    }else {
    include process2
    }

}
```

Comment: If a user somehow figures out the "start.php" points to either "process1.php" or "process2.php", s/he will be able to figure out that s/he can simply type into the browser address bar "proccess1.php" or "process2.php".  How do I stop that?

Comment: Set a access KEY in the if else statements and check for that access key in the process files.  check edit

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php and search for further tutorials on google.

If you really want to make things easyer and more maintainable in php you should start to use object oriented programming.

You could then have one class distribute all your requests, another to process them and a third one to render the results ;)